# How do I select the most recent records from a table full of duplicates

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've got the below table and need a query to produce the expected result.

```
**Table**
  Address Num  My_Date
 Address1 7777 03/NOV/15
 Address2 2222 02/NOV/15
 Address2 3333 02/NOV/15
 Address2 2222 05/NOV/15
 Address2 3333 05/NOV/15
 Address3 8888 01/NOV/15
 Address4 9999 04/NOV/15
```

**Expected Result**

```
Address  Num  My_Date
Address1 7777 03/NOV/15
Address2 2222 05/NOV/15
Address2 3333 05/NOV/15
Address3 8888 01/NOV/15
Address4 9999 04/NOV/15
```

As you can see , I need to bring back all the records and if there is a duplicate *Num* bring only the records that have the most recent *My_Date*.

Comment: Does your data only have three columns or are there additional columns you want to bring back?

Comment: Hi Gordon,  I need additional fields added,  ive got around this by just adding these fields after the num field as part of the normal field definition and the group by clause,  is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either do a `GROUP BY`:

```
select address, num, max(date)
from tablename
group by address, num
```

Or a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.address = t1.address
                    and t2.num = t1.num
                    and t2.date > t1.date)
```

In ANSI SQL date is a reserved word, so probably you need to double quote it as a delimited identifier, i.e. `"date"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use below query to get u r required o/p

```
select "Address","Num","Date"
from
(
select "Address","Num","Date",rank() over(partition by "Address" order by "Date" desc) r_no from table_name
)
where r_no=1
```

Comment: Given the OP's comments, this seems to be the correct solution (although I would use `row_number()` rather than `rank()` to ensure that only one row per address is chosen).